# Python find the frequency of combinations in 2 lists

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 lists,

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A']
```

How can I find the frequency for each combinations of `'a''A'`, `'b''B'` and `'c''C'` ?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697709/comparing-two-lists-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Use the aptly named `Counter`, from `collections`, like this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(zip(['a','b','c','a'],['A','B','C','A'])).most_common()
[(('a', 'A'), 2), (('b', 'B'), 1), (('c', 'C'), 1)]
```

`zip` quickly creates the pairs of objects that should be compared:

```
>>> zip(['a','b','c','a'],['A','B','C','A'])
[('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B'), ('c', 'C'), ('a', 'A')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is okay, but it needs `list1` and `list2` to be sorted and to have equal number of each letter.

Below program works for all cases:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A']

for letter in ascii_lowercase:
    if letter in list1 and letter.capitalize() in list2:        
        n1 = list1.count(letter)
        n2 = list2.count(letter.capitalize())
        print letter,'-',letter.capitalize(), min(n1,n2)
```

Output:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
a - A 2
b - B 1
c - C 1
>>>
```